# org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 292,column 0: junk after document element

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-xmlpullparser

I am new to XML Parsing, I need to take url feeds and parse them, then save them in the local database. If I pass some other Link it accepts but if I pass the link that I need It give this error.
I am also providing my code part and log cat output along with this.
Can anyone tell me what sort of problem I am facing?

Following is the URL which I need to parse.

```
private static final String POSTS_URL = "http://bgr.in/feed/iphoneapp";
```

This is the method where the error is generated:-

```
public static void updateStories(Context context, String url, int type) {
    if (StoryService.isConnected(context)) {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.addHeader("accepts", "application/rss+xml");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get rss feed.", e);
        }

        RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");

        List<BaseStory> stories = Story.appendArrayListener(type, 
                root.getChild("channel"), 0);

        try {
            Xml.parse(response.getEntity().getContent(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to parse " + url, e);
        }`public static void updateStories(Context context, String url, int type) {
    if (StoryService.isConnected(context)) {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.addHeader("accepts", "application/rss+xml");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get rss feed.", e);
        }

        RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");

        List<BaseStory> stories = Story.appendArrayListener(type, 
                root.getChild("channel"), 0);

        try {
            Xml.parse(response.getEntity().getContent(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to parse " + url, e);
        }
```

The Log Cat Output is as follows:-

```
System.err(19251):  org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 292,column 0: junk after document element
System.err(19251):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:515)
System.err(19251):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:474)
System.err(19251):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:316)
System.err(19251):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:279)
System.err(19251):  at android.util.Xml.parse(Xml.java:84)
System.err(19251):  at in.bgr.service.StoryService.updateStories(StoryService.java:122)
System.err(19251):  at in.bgr.service.StoryService.updateStories(StoryService.java:96)
System.err(19251):  at in.bgr.ui.AllStoriesFragment$LoadStoriesTask.doInBackground(AllStoriesFragment.java:309)
System.err(19251):  at in.bgr.ui.AllStoriesFragment$LoadStoriesTask.doInBackground(AllStoriesFragment.java:1)
System.err(19251):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
System.err(19251):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
System.err(19251):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
System.err(19251):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"junk after document element" error is caused where there is any unwanted tag in the xml after root element tag. just removes all those tags which are there after the root element tag.
In my case there was a repeated entry of XML element at the line number 292 in the XML file. I cleared it and now I think it will work for me.